# Application crashes when image selected from gallery in android mobile - Ionic framework Cordova

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

```
  $scope.showPopup = function() {
        $scope.data = {}
        var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
            title: 'Add a photo',
            subTitle: 'Choose from Camera or Gallery',
            scope: $scope,
            buttons: [
            {
              text: '<i class="icon ion-camera"></i>',
              type: 'button-stable',
              onTap: function(e) {
                $scope.addPic(1);
                return 'done';
              }
            },
            {
                text: '<i class="icon ion-image"></i>',
                type: 'button-stable',
                onTap: function(e) {
                    $scope.addPic(0);
                    return 'done';
                }
          }
        ]
    });
    myPopup.then(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    });
};


    $scope.addPic = function(source){
        var options = {
            quality : 50,
            destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: source,
            allowEdit : true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 125,
            targetHeight: 125,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="picture"; ...............
```

The above code gives a pop up from where user can choose photo upload either directly from camera or from Gallery. I am testing the application on android phone (android version 4.2.2)
This code works perfectly fine when user chooses for upload from Camera(sourcetype:1) but it crashes for upload from gallery.

How do I proceed? Please guide me on this.

Comment: @priyanaka How did you solve this?

Comment: I am facing same kind of issue, did you solve it?